# Ionic Native GooglePlus login is not working without any error and console

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-signin, ionic-native

Before it worked well, now it is not working

I have used following plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus
```

Code for login is simple as in instruction:

```
this.googlePlus.login({})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.0.2, (and 34 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Volumes/mac_data/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Cordova version 7.1.0

Ionic Native GooglePlus 5.3.0

"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.12.0",
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.0

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**Downgrade cordova-plugin-googleplus to ^5.2.1,**

`ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-googleplus`

`npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/google-plus`

**Second**

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus@5.2.1 --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

`npm install @ionic-native/google-plus`

Answer (score 2):

Check the SHA1 certificate, During pushing your application to google play store, the SHA1 is auto generated by google in the latest update.
To resolve this you need to use the auto generated SHA1 every time & configure with this SHA1 certificate in your google account.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this problem removing and readding android platform, I use android platform 7.1.4 and cordova 8 as well ( under win10 ).

But beware, from my experience doing this will probably raise some kind of other issues related to plugin compatibility.

Currently I have a compatibility problem with google plus and admob free plugin ( "desugar" error when building ) that raised exactly when I encountered your same issue ( google plus plugin doing anything ) and then removed and readded the android platform.

When install only one of those plugins everything works.

So try this solution if you are comfortable with the command platform rm/add.

-- edit

You can try this solution without any risks doing a checkout of your project in another dir :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on the **Playstore** version. We need to get the Auto-generated SHA1 key here and put that under `Firebase Project Settings --> Fingerprint`

Get the Auto-Generated SHA1 key like so:

[image]

Comment: This is working. But I am quite confused because I got release fingerprint executing keytool command which is different from the one which is in playconsole

Comment: @mitu1234 You MUST use the Play console one like so above.